# CSS file inaccessible via URL, but shows up in SFTP folder

Tags: .htaccess, permissions, expressionengine

I have an odd problem where I can't access a CSS file directly via a web browser even though I see the file on the SFTP folder.

The folder and the CSS file have 777 permissions and I can see adaptive.css in the directory along with app.css.

However http://www.adaptiveemails.com/stylesheets/app.css works, but http://www.adaptiveemails.com/stylesheets/adaptive.css doesn't show up.

UPDATE: I made a new file directly in the SFTP client and copied the same content from adaptive.css into the new file and it worked fine.

UPDATE 2: It looks like it may be an htaccess issue because it's only happening when the file is named "adaptive.css". Any other name works fine. I'm using ExpressionEngine and their MSM and maybe the htaccess file or something similar is causing this issue.

HTACCESS FILE IN ROOT:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Links are wrong: http://www.adaptiveemails.com/stylesheets/app.css and http://www.adaptiveemails.com/stylesheets/adaptive.css are the ones you are using. Anyways, I think you are forgetting to give web access to that CSS file.

Comment: Both styles have 777 applied and are in the same directory. I changed the link line to use single quotes. See even clicking on the link directly to the second CSS file doesn't work, but the first does?

Comment: Web access is another thing. I think you will get more success if you change your question into that direction.

Comment: Are you running Apache Server or nginx?  Might be time to enable the Rewrite Log and see what you find there...

Answer (score 0):

First thing first you need you file modifications as 754. I am guessing because you have (double) double quotes in your text/css that's why it's not working.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the links in the post it self.